# How to extract text from inside div

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract this:
[image]

from this link : https://www.arabam.com/ilan/sahibinden-satilik-peugeot-407-2-0-hdi-comfort/sahibinden-peugeot-407-1-6-hdi-comfort-2008-model/12776039

I'm using `scrapy` to extract the information.

**Edit** : I tried extracting text this way but nothing: `response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/dl[1]/dd/span")`

If somebody wants to recreate then just copy paste this code and run. You can take any page, just need to extract that information.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import googletrans
# from googletrans import Translator
from translate import Translator

class Myspider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'spidername'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_1.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/otomobil/', 'parse'),
        # ('/category/', 'parse_category'),
    ]
    def parse(self,response):


            for td in response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/a/@href").extract():
                # / html / body / div[3] / div[6] / div[4] / div / div[2] / table / tbody / tr / td[4] / div / a
                checks = str(td.split("/")[3]).split("-")

                for items in checks:
                    if items.isdigit():

                        if int(items) > 2001:

                            url = "https://www.arabam.com/"+ td
                            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)


    def parse_dir_contents(self,response):
        ##some other stuff im scraping

        overview1 = response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/dl[1]/dd/span")
        print(response)
        print("s"+ str(overview1))



process = CrawlerProcess({

})

process.crawl(Myspider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the c
```

rawling is finished

Edit: Expected output is to get these exact key value pairs.

Edit: Using tag in answer Im getting this:

```
[......or Kaputu: ', ' Orijinal ', '  ', 'Sol Ön Çamurluk: ', ' Boyanmış ', '  ', 'Ön Tampon: ', ' Orijinal ', '  ', 'Arka Tampon: ', ' Orijinal ', '  ', 'Belirtilmemiş', 'Orijinal', 'Boyalı', 'Değişmiş', '   ', '  ', ' Tramer tutarı yok ', '  ', '  ', '  ', 'ARAÇ BİLGİLERİ', '  ', ' ', 'DONANIM', '\xa0', '  ', '\xa0', '  ', '\xa0', '  ', '\xa0', '  ', '\xa0', '  ', '\xa0', '  ', '  ', 'KREDİ', '  ', '  ', 'SPONSORLU BAĞLANTILAR', " googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1547030262883-0'); }); ", " googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1547030358839-0'); }); "]
```

Edit:
I have tried getting it through Selenium still no luck

```
 element = d.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div")
        d.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        element = d.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div")
        print(element)
        overview1 = element.text
```

Edit:
Since element is in the middle of screen it doesn't get into view. Is there any way to scroll to bottom and then to middle. I have tried this code doesn't work:

```
element = d.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div')  # you can use ANY way to locate element
        coordinates = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view  # returns dict of X, Y coordinates
        d.execute_script('window.scrollTo({}, {});'.format(coordinates['x'], coordinates['y']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following using selenium to test the xpaths (I've not used scrapy before):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.arabam.com/ilan/sahibinden-satilik-peugeot-407-2-0-hdi-comfort/sahibinden-peugeot-407-1-6-hdi-comfort-2008-model/12776039'


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080);")

sleep(1)

overview_info = [ data for section in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-6 genel-bakis']") for data in section.text.split("\n")]
enguine_info = [ data for section in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-6 motor-ve-performans']") for data in section.text.split("\n")]

print("VEHICLE INFORMATION")
for i in range(0,len(overview_info)-1,2):
    print(overview_info[i] + ": " + overview_info[i+1])
for i in range(0,len(enguine_info)-1,2):
    print(enguine_info[i] + ": " + enguine_info[i+1])

driver.quit()
```

This gives my the following output:

[image]

The output is what you have highlighted in the picture so I suggest you use the paths:

```
#Get the text in the general section
"//div[@class='col-md-6 genel-bakis']//text()"
#Get text in the engine and performance section
"//div[@class='col-md-6 motor-ve-performans']//text()"
```

Comment: I am not getting data as you have mentioned. I have mentioned it in question as well. Kindly guide